# What are the permissions to get admin_view in response to REST API: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?viewType=admin_view'

Tags: view, admin, google-admin-sdk

While using Google Admin SDK REST API (fetch list of users in a domain): https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=', I have always encountered 403 (Not authorized error).
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"

However, if I change the value for only one of the query parameters, namely, viewType to 'domain_public' from 'admin_view', it succeeds. So, it indicates that the account I am using to invoke this query does not have requisite privileges for 'admin_view'.

I am using G-suite account for executing the REST API and it does not have SUPER ADMIN privileges. Again, for security reasons, I do not want to assign unlimited privileges to this user.

So, I have two pointed queries here:

1. What could be precise set of permissions to get 'admin_view' for above REST API ?
2. Instead of using a G-Suite user-account, how about creating a service account that is associated with a custom/out-of-the-box role comprising all requisite permissions and use that service account to launch the REST API query ? Will it work ? I feel this to be more secure and more appropriate way 'theoretically' ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the used account is not an administrator on the domain and therefore cannot access the Admin View Directory API.

To solve the issue add [delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) and then, in face of the following note

> Only users with access to the Admin APIs can access the Admin
>   SDK Directory API, therefore your service account needs to impersonate
>   one of those users to access the Admin SDK Directory API.
>   Additionally, the user must have logged in at least once and accepted
>   the G Suite Terms of Service.

impersonate a domain admin when you make the request:

```
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    $authArray,
    $key
);
$cred->sub = "admin@yourdomain.com";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... I have following as follow-up queries:
1) If the user has to be an admin account, is this possible to have Read-only permissions ? I cannot have an admin account with any sort of write, execute permissions.

2) The whole point for calling this API is to find out whether MFA is enabled for a particular user or not. Is there any alternative API to find this out ?